# Can urls contain dots in the path part?

Tags: url

Is this a valid URL? (from a standard point of view)

```
http://test.com/some/path/version/1.2/thing
```

Comment: test.com has a dot, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but I'm asking for the "path" part, according to the wikipedia page on url : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax
test.com is the domain, not the path. Upgraded the question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes. This is common for versioning web service interfaces. See spec: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

Comment: For whoever is also looking into the spec: At the end you can see that path can contain segment and segment can contain xpalpha which can contain xaplha which can contain "safe" which can contain a dot.

Comment: so a ../ means previous "folder" but ./ means a "subfolder" named .?

Comment: First comment is GOOD, I'll just make it more readable LOL: `path` -> `segment` -> `xpalphas` -> `xalpha` -> `alpha | digit | safe | extra | escape` -> `safe = $ | - | _ | @ | . | &  | + | -`

Answer (score 35):

Obviously it is possible. Here is an example

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html.

Comment: +1 for real world example. That said, it don't means it's acceptable from a standard point of view.