# Best format for adding a version id into a URL path

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I'm currently re-working an application and want to add in a version number to the application URL paths. For example:

`http://mydomain/app/VERSION-ID/resource/...`

My question is, what is the correct or standard format to add a version id to a URL string? Is there any disadvantage to just having it numeric (1.1 or 1-1):

`Example: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json`

Or is it better to have a non numeric identifier to be more intuitive as the url is public facing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use dots in a URL unless you're defining domain spaces. Use either dashes or other truncated versions (that don't use disallowed characters in the URL).

EXAMPLE:

```
Example: https://api.twitter.com/v1-1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

**UPDATE:** Here is some more information in another thread. My preference is not to use dots if at all possible, but it is apparently OK to do.

[Can urls contain dots in the path part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777274/can-urls-contain-dots-in-the-path-part)

Comment: I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with using periods, as it seems to be widely used for version ids.

Comment: Can see your point, is it just bad practice to use dots or would it actually cause any routing problems when navigating through the application?

Comment: Considering it is used on [github](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/tree/2.0/master), I wouldn't think so. I am no expert on the subject, however.

Comment: Thanks, looks like dots are fine to use however I think the format of /v1-1/ is a good shout as it makes it obvious that the id is for a version.