# Python: URL parsing issue while adding a trailing slash

Tags: python, url, url-parsing

I was developing a small experiment in python to normalize a URL. My main purpose is to add slash `/` at the end of the URL if it is not already present. for example if it is `http://www.example.com` then it should be converted to `http://www.example.com/`

Here is a small snippet for the same:

```
if url[len(url)-1] != "/":
        url = url + "/"
```

But this also converts file names. For example `http://www.example.com/image.png` into `http://www.example.com/image.png/` which is wrong. I just want to add slash to directory and not file names. How do i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pattern match on the last substring to check for known domains vs file extensions. It's not too difficult to enumerate at least the basic [top level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) like .com, .gov, .org, etc.

If you are familiar with regular extensions, you can match on a pattern like `'.com$'`.

Otherwise, you can split by '.' and check the last substring you get:

```
In [32]: url_png = 'http://www.example.com/image.png'

In [33]: url_com = 'http://www.example.com'

In [34]: domains = ['com', 'org', 'gov']

In [35]: for url in [url_png, url_com]:
   ....:     suffix = url.split('.')[-1]
   ....:     if suffix in domains:
   ....:         print url
   ....:
http://www.example.com
```

As a side note and as you see in the above example, you don't need to do `url[len(url)-1]` to index the last element of a list; the Pythonic way is just `url[-1]`.

Comment: well your snippet actually solved my other related problem pertaining to this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You gotta ensure that whenever a `.` comes in URL, for directory it should be in the hostname. If its anywhere else, it is a file name.
So for this, just do `url.count('.')` and check if that is greater than the ones in your hostname (eg, in here its equal to 2)

```
if url.count('.') > 2:
    url = url if url[-1] != '/' else url[:-1]
else:
    url = url  if url[-1] == '/' else url + '/'
```

Comment: but there can be a valid url like `http://www.example.com/1.2/1.3/1.4/index.html` refer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777274/can-urls-contain-dots-in-the-path-part)

Comment: This is much simpler than my response and should work most of the time, though you would need to select the first substring after http:// before a /. But I don't think hostnames are limited to a single subdomain...

Comment: not only subdomains will bring extra `.` but dots are also allowed in the URL path itself...which makes the above technique very difficult to use and may give out wrong results...