# How to check the equality of two identical URLs if one of them has "www"?

Tags: c#, .net

The following URLs are identical:

- **http://example.com**
- **http://www.example.com**

Can I get the expected result using a method provided in .Net framework like Compare() method in Uri class? or should I handle this case manually?

Comment: I really doubt there is a standart solution, because *technically* these URLs are not identical and can lead to different pages. So you have to handle them manually.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser is correct.  Your assertion that "The following URLs are identical" is flawed.  They are not.  Now _usually_ both of these domain names will resolve to the same host machine.  And even if they don't, _usually_ they will return the same content.  But they most certainly aren't the same URL.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. I mean they are "identical" because they return the same result, so I want to consider them identical using a method provided by .NET, it seems that Uri.Compare method doesn't work because they are technically not identical, so I need to implement my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to leave a simple comment for you to ponder about so I'll just leave an answer as food for thought.

I can see a few possible solutions which should cover most scenarios (I'm pretty certain I will probably miss quite a few but everyone makes mistakes):

1. Use a loop to move over both URIs and compare each part/component as you see fit with break early conditions to speed it up
2. Clean up the URIs as much as you can using arbitrarily defined rules (eg. remove protocol, remove www prefix, trim ending /) then use Equals() to compare
3. If you're feeling bold you could use something similar to lexical analysis to convert both URIs into a objects/tokens/parts and compare the subsequent result (harder to implement but probably the most accurate)

Just keep in mind that the guys in the comments are right. The URLs aren't technically the same and the logic you implement in your ultimate solution is purely defined around your definition of 'identical'.

Also, I wouldn't use the solution that simple replaces "www." with "" since someone crazy [could easily put a 'www.' somewhere else in their URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777274/can-urls-contain-dots-in-the-path-part) and break that implementation unless you perform the replace on both URLs which is also quite risky since one could have more 'www.' instances than the other and would still be considered 'identical'

Comment: Although your 'comment' is valid. It is way too complex when introducing your own lexical analysis. If anything, most languages provide regular expressions or at the very least `string` manipulation - so something like `string.split` will be more efficient in terms of work done vs benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, these are actually not identical urls and cannot be treated as such.

That aside, it may help you to check the equality after removing the www part:

```
string urla = @"http://example.com";
string urlb = @"http://www.example.com";

if (urlb.contains("www.")) urlb = urlb.replace("www.", "");
if (urla == urlb) {
    // url matches
}
```

Comment: Probably should only compare with the host part  urla.Host.xxxx == urlb.Host.xxxx that way it don't matter on the urla.Scheme either (ie. http, https)